# WebDriver filtering list of elements

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

how to efficiently find and filter list of elements.
here is the HTML

```
<span class="tab-strip-text" unselectable="on">Admin</span>
<span class="tab-strip-text" unselectable="on">User</span>
<span class="tab-strip-text" unselectable="on">Reports</span>
<span class="tab-strip-text" unselectable="on">Logs</span>
```

currently i am using following method to find and filter and click on the element i want based on text

```
public static void clickTab(String tabText){
  List<WebElement> tabs = driver.findElements(By.className("tab-strip-text"));      
    for(WebElement tab : tabs){
        if(tab.getText().equals(tabText)){
            tab.click();
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```

is there better way to find and iterate over list (to click based on text() of elements?)

thx

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath with the text you are after in your locators.

```
//*[@class='tab-strip-text' and text()='Reports']
```

Then you have:

```
WebElement reportTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='tab-strip-text' and text()='Reports']"));
reportTab.click();
```

Note I don't encourage you to use text in your locators if your site supports multi-languages. In that case, the best way is to add meaningful class names to your source of each element.

Comment: @aeinstein83: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

try this xpath

```
    //span[contains(text(),'Reports')]

String value="text you are looking for";

public void method(String value){
driver.findElements(By.xpath( //span[contains(text(),'"+value+"')])).click();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont think method `click()` is defined for `List<WebElement)`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post for long time ago but i guess someone will look for a solution :)

```
tabs.forEach(tab -> {
    if(tab.getText().equals(tabText)){
        tab.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Using Stream filter(). This will help you to click on element based on given text.

filter returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.

```
List<WebElement> categories = driver.findElements(By.className("tab-strip-text"));
categories.stream().filter(ele->ele.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Admin")).forEach(ele -> ele.click());
```